# How to animate a CALayer to have empty contents

Tags: uiimage, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have a `CALayer` with an image in it, and it has several sublayers. I want to animate it to have no contents (no image), but continue showing the sublayers. This code does not work:

```
   CABasicAnimation *backgroundOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
   backgroundOut.toValue = [NSNull null];
   backgroundOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
   backgroundOut.removedOnCompletion = NO;
   backgroundOut.duration = 3.0;
   [_backgroundLayer addAnimation:backgroundOut forKey:@"contents"];
```

Here is the only way I could get this to work:

```
   backgroundOut.toValue = (__bridge id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"blankImage"].CGImage);
```

Note that I don't want to mess with the opacity or anything because this layer has sublayers that need to still be visible.

What is the proper way to animate to empty contents?

Comment: Have you tried backgroundOut.toValue = (id)nil ?

Comment: Yes, setting the toValue to nil was something I tried. It does not work because that effectively means us the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided this was the cleanest approach, since there was no other answer forthcoming:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, 1), NO, 0);
    UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CABasicAnimation *backgroundOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    backgroundOut.toValue = (__bridge id)(blank.CGImage);
    backgroundOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    backgroundOut.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    backgroundOut.duration = 3.0;

    [_backgroundLayer addAnimation:backgroundOut forKey:@"contents"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to create a separate layer to contain your image that is a peer of your other layers, but just behind the other layers (you can use zposition to place it behind the other layers explicitly)--all contained within a root layer. Then, you can animate the image layer's alpha for a fade and won't have the overhead of creating an image on the fly and it won't then fade the other layers.

Comment: Yes, that would work as well. I was hoping to be able to get away without the extra layer, but it sounds like a good approach.